# Salesforce Org Shape Error authentication

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error, org-shape

I'm passsing for this error, when i run the command ***sfdx force:org:shape:list***

**ERROR running force:org:shape:list:  Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: expired access/refresh token**

I already try to logout the user and loggin again, and I alreary re-install the sfdx pluggin but nothing works to me, someone have already passed thought this?

Comment: Is the issue happening for all the commands? What version is your Salesforce CLI?

Comment: No @MohithShrivastava just for this command, the other commands like force:details are running, my sfdx version is sfdx-cli/7.174.0 win32-x64 node-v16.17.1

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Salesforce CLI is v56.3.1

Comment: Are you connected to the DevHub that has Org Shape permissions enabled?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava yes

Answer (score 1):

The solution was clean all the organizations with error in my **sfdx force:org:list** command, one by one, after that the command runned perfect.